# What does "to present a foil against something" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Doing some translation for my friend, I met the following sentence.

> For Foppe Ten Hoor, it presented a foil against Anglo-American — and
>   not coincidentally, Arminian, subbiblical — ways.

It is from a book titled "Reformed Theology in America: A History of Its Modern Development." For its context, see this capture, which I capture from [Google Books](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=S_ja7y27VYsC&lpg=PA140&dq=%22it%20presented%20a%20foil%20against%22&pg=PA140#v=onepage&q=%22it%20presented%20a%20foil%20against%22&f=false).

[image]

I couldn't figure out what "presented a foil" means, so checked online dictionary.

Merriam Webster has three entries for foil as a noun;

> foil
>   noun (1)
>
> 1: very thin sheet metal aluminum foil 
>   2: a thin piece of material (such as metal) put under an inferior or paste 
>   stone to add color or brilliance 
>   **3: someone or something that serves as a contrast to another** 
>   *acted as a foil for a comedian* 
>   4 a: an indentation between cusps in Gothic tracery 
>   b: one of several arcs that enclose a complex
>   figure 5: HYDROFOIL sense 1
>
> foil 
>   noun (2) 
>   1: a light fencing sword having a usually circular guard and a flexible blade > of rectangular section tapering to a blunted point — compare ÉPÉE, SABER 
>   2: the art or sport of fencing with the foil —often used in plural
>
> foil 
>   noun (3)
>   1 archaic : DEFEAT
>   2 archaic : the track or trail of an animal

I guess the definition in 1-3 seems fit to this case. Do I understand its meaning right? Or could you propose a rephrase for 'present a foil against'?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, your selected definition from Merriam Webster is the correct one.

Comment: @KillingTime You should expand that into an answer to prevent guesses.

Answer (score -1):

I have always understood a [**foil**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/foil) to be a noun form of the verb.

> **foil**
>   VERB
>   Prevent (something considered wrong or undesirable) from succeeding.

I see it as a metaphorical use of the "light fencing sword" you mention: a *strategy* to deflect something undesirable.

Comment: Yes; [Wiktionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/foil) is the only dictionary I've found not to label this sense as archaic: << **foil** Noun
(plural foils):

Failure when on the point of attainment; defeat; frustration; miscarriage. >> (AHD, a repulse / setback.)

Answer (score -1):

As in:   Vocabulary.com verb: to foil

- > ... it [**hindered** or prevented the efforts, plans, or desires](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/foil)
  >   of the Anglo-American ways.

As a verb, if you foil someone's plans or attempts to do something, you cause them to fail.

Comment: Here, a foil is only a counterpart, the way a straight man is a counterpart to a comedian.

Answer (score -1):

The Word Detective has an article on this subject.

http://www.word-detective.com/2011/12/foiled/

*“Foil,” closely related to that “full,” also first appeared in English in the 14th century, with the specific sense of “to trample down,” and eventually developed a sense specific to hunting meaning “to trample down and thus obscure a track or scent, thus preventing hounds from tracking the game.” This “foiling” could be done by other animals or even by the hounds themselves. In either case, it marked a defeat for the hunters, and by the 16th century “foil” was being used in its modern sense to mean “to defeat, to block, to baffle a foe.”*